# Java Jsoup fail to parse page

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to parse berkeley homes found at this url http://www.berkeleygroup.co.uk/search-results

My problem is that it only selects the first element but there are 35 in the page.  How can I print all 35 elements?

My code looks like this:

```
 String url = "http://www.berkeleygroup.co.uk/search-results";
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 "
                + "(Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                + "Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
                .timeout(10000).followRedirects(false).get();
 Elements initialTag = doc.select("ul.list.lazyloadsearchcontainer > li");

 for (Element e : initialTag) {
        String print = e.text();
        System.out.println(print);
 }
```

**Edit Why is BS for python working and not Java JSoup?

** Inspecting the source page, it appears the text is hidden in a JQuery $(document).ready(function($){ and once loaded prints the text to each property box.  How can I parse JavaScript JQuery, an extension to JSoup?

Comment: I find 62 elements. (using BS for python, but that's quite the same)

Comment: is it printing all 62 elements?

Comment: and yes, all 62 of them are printing

Comment: 62 lines for me too, however only one line has something printable

Comment: what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you only retrieve one item is the page source displays the first item in its markup. However, the browser renders a client-side javascript pulling from JSON data in a jquery function. So what you see in browser is not what the JSoup parses from page source. Welcome to the new, dynamic world of web programming!

With that said, if you still need to extract the page's JSON data, consider using JSoup to extract the `<script>` content and then you can grab the JSON data (using its [DataNode](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/DataNode.html) property) from the `var aUpdatedDevelopments`. Below parses the first two script tags to text file and outputs to screen:

```
    // Set Current Directory 
    String currentDir = new File("").getAbsolutePath();

    // Open text file
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(currentDir + "/BerkeleyGroupScrape.txt");

    // Connect to HTML page and get content     
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.berkeleygroup.co.uk/search-results").timeout(10*1000).get();

    Elements scriptTags = doc.getElementsByTag("script");

    int i = 0;      
    for (Element tag : scriptTags){         

        if (i > 2) { continue; }
        for (DataNode node : tag.dataNodes()) {
            System.out.println(node.getWholeData());
            writer.append(node.getWholeData());
            i++;
        }

    }   

    // Close text file
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
var __stormJs ='t1.stormiq.com/dcv4/jslib/6525_E9642FE4_B222_4C82_B6CA_7F4D662CB825.js';

var device_width=screen.width;var device_height=screen.height;var dpr=1;
if(window.devicePixelRatio!==undefined)
{dpr=window.devicePixelRatio;}if(device_width>device_height)
{ai_width=device_width;}else{ai_width=device_height;}var data = 
{dpr:dpr,resolution:ai_width};$.ajax({url:"/api.cfc?method=setClientVariables
",type:"POST",data:data,success:function(d,st,xhr){},error:function(xhr,st,e)
{}});


                                                <!--

                                                        $(document).ready(function($){

                                                                var aUpdatedDevelopments = '{"ROWCOUNT":56,"COLUMNS":
["ICON","LAT","LONGI","BESTLINKTEXT","FRIENDLYURL","DEVINTROTEXT","DEVHEADING
","DEVSTATUS","PRICERANGE","DEVIMAGE","DEVLOGO","DIVISION"],"DATA":{"ICON":
["\/media\/logo\/6\/r\/one-tower-bridge-map-logo-image-black.png","\/media
\/logo\/d\/t\/berkeley-homes-woodberry-down-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo
\/7\/j\/st-james-heritage-walk-development-logo-map-v2.png","\/media\/logo
\/i\/k\/st-george-sovereign-court-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/j\/k
\/st-george-one-blackfriars-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/s\/o\/berkeley-
250-city-road-marketing-location-map-logo-v3.png","\/media\/logo\/r\/9
\/berkeley-taplow-riverside-map-logo-v2.png","\/media\/logo\/i\/3\/st-james-
smithfield-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/o\/s\/berkeley-royal-wells-park-map-
logo.png","\/media\/logo\/b\/7\/st-george-battersea-reach-map-logo.png","
\/media\/logo\/d\/5\/berkeley-vista-logo-map.png","\/media\/logo\/8\/4
\/berkeley-woodhurst-park-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/d\/5\/berkeley-
queenshurst-map-search-logo-v2_33.png","\/media\/logo\/j\/g\/st-george-
kew-bridge-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/j\/a\/berkeley-green-park-village-
map-logo-updated-v2.png","\/media\/logo\/h\/0\/st-james-fiennes-park-logo-
map.png","\/media\/logo\/t\/c\/st-james-albert-embankment-corniche-
map-search.png","\/media\/logo\/f\/a\/st-george-dickens-yard-map-logo.png","
\/media\/logo\/i\/8\/st-edward-375-kensington-high-street-map-logo.png","
\/media\/logo\/i\/8\/st-james-riverlight-map-logo1.png","\/media\/logo\/i\/8
\/berkeley-homes-the-ashmiles-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/d\/b\/berkeley-
kennet-island-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/1\/1\/berkeley-oakgrove-
map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/d\/8\/st-george-chelsea-creek-map-logo.png","
\/media\/logo\/j\/b\/berkeley-homes-holborough-lakes-map-logo.png","\/media
\/logo\/b\/q\/berkeley-victory-pier-development-logo-on-white-map.png","
\/media\/logo\/4\/8\/berkeley-homes-kidbrooke-village-map-logo.png","\/media
\/logo\/l\/h\/st-george-london-dock-map-search-icon.png","\/media\/logo\/2\/9
\/berkeley-homes-abell-and-cleland-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/e\/0
\/berkeley-wye-dene-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/i\/k\/st-edward-kensington-
row-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/f\/q\/st-george-beaufort-park-map-
logo.png","\/media\/logo\/0\/d\/berkeley-homes-highwood-map-logo.png","
\/media\/logo\/7\/o\/berkeley-walnut-grove-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/7\/c
\/st-james-hurlingham-walk-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/3\/b\/berkeley-
homes-edenbrook-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/2\/j\/berkeley-ryewood-
map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/j\/j\/berkeley-marine-wharf-map-logo.png","
\/media\/logo\/j\/0\/berkeley-brunswick-square-map-logo-v2.png","\/media
\/logo\/p\/b\/st-edward-stanmore-place-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/g\/k
\/berkeley-homes-wimbledon-hill-park-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/8\/0
\/Berkeley-south-quay-plaza-map-search-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/l\/i
\/st-james-kew-bridge-west-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/3\/0\/st-james-
southall-gasworks-map-logo.png","\/media\/logo\/h\/c\/st-james-dumont-
map-logo1.png","\/me
...
```

[JSON Pretty Print](http://jsonprettyprint.com/) *(extracting the value of aUpdatedDevelopments variable above)*

```
{
  "ROWCOUNT": 56,
  "COLUMNS": [
    "ICON",
    "LAT",
    "LONGI",
    "BESTLINKTEXT",
    "FRIENDLYURL",
    "DEVINTROTEXT",
    "DEVHEADING",
    "DEVSTATUS",
    "PRICERANGE",
    "DEVIMAGE",
    "DEVLOGO",
    "DIVISION"
  ],
  "DATA": {
    "ICON": [
      "\/media\/logo\/6\/r\/one-tower-bridge-map-logo-image-black.png",
      "\/media\/logo\/d\/t\/berkeley-homes-woodberry-down-map-logo.png",
      "\/media\/logo\/7\/j\/st-james-heritage-walk-development-logo-map-v2.png",
      "\/media\/logo\/i\/k\/st-george-sovereign-court-map-logo.png",
      "\/media\/logo\/j\/k\/st-george-one-blackfriars-map-logo.png",
      "\/media\/logo\/s\/o\/berkeley-250-city-road-marketing-location-map-logo-v3.png",
      "\/media\/logo\/r\/9\/berkeley-taplow-riverside-map-logo-v2.png",
      "\/media\/logo\/i\/3\/st-james-smithfield-map-logo.png",
      "\/media\/logo\/o\/s\/berkeley-royal-wells-park-map-logo.png",
...
"LAT": [
      51.5038122197,
      51.5707487583,
      51.4884271,
      51.494341,
      51.507878,
      51.528207,
      51.5292685,
      51.5879838,
      51.1355008763,
      51.4647143,
      51.4802827,
      51.427478,
      51.414314,
      51.488669,
      51.4251047,
      51.514982,
...
"BESTLINKTEXT": [
      "One Tower Bridge",
      "Woodberry Down",
      "Heritage Walk",
      "Sovereign Court",
      "One Blackfriars",
      "250 City Road",
      "Taplow Riverside",
      "Smithfield Square",
      "Royal Wells Park",
      "Battersea Reach",
      "Vista, Chelsea Bridge",
      "Woodhurst Park",
      "Queenshurst",
      "Kew Bridge",
      "Green Park Village",
      "Fiennes Park",
      "The Corniche",
      "Dickens Yard",
      "375 Kensington High Street",
...
 "FRIENDLYURL": [
      "\/new-homes\/london\/tower-bridge\/one-tower-bridge",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/finsbury-park\/woodberry-down",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/kew-bridge\/heritage-walk",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/hammersmith\/sovereign-court",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/southwark\/one-blackfriars",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/islington\/250-city-road",
      "\/new-homes\/buckinghamshire\/taplow\/taplow-riverside",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/hornsey\/smithfield-square",
      "\/new-homes\/kent\/royal-tunbridge-wells\/royal-wells-park",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/battersea\/battersea-reach",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/battersea\/vista-chelsea-bridge",
      "\/new-homes\/berkshire\/warfield\/woodhurst-park",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/kingston\/queenshurst",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/kew-bridge\/kew-bridge",
      "\/new-homes\/berkshire\/reading\/green-park-village",
      "\/new-homes\/berkshire\/maidenhead\/fiennes-park",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/albert-embankment\/the-corniche",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/ealing\/dickens-yard",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/kensington\/375-kensington-high-street",
      "\/new-homes\/london\/vauxhall\/riverlight",
      "\/new-homes\/west-sussex\/barns-green\/the-ashmiles",
      "\/new-homes\/berkshire\/reading\/kennet-island",
```